# How to convert this associative array into this json output using json_encode()

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I have this php associative array.

```
array(
                'Location_1' => 'Link_1',
                'Location_2' => 'Link_2'
    )
```

I would like to convert it into a json output using json_encode() that looks like this;

```
[{"Location_name":"Location_1","Link_name":"Link_1"},{"Location_name":"Location_2","Link_name":"Link_2"}]
```

How can this be done? The challenging part to me seems like how to add the Location_name and Link_name in front. Thank you very much.

Comment: try getting our PHP model in line with your JSON Model, and you'll get the rest for free.  Note that the JSON you're showing is an _array_ of hashes (associative arrays) but in PHP you aren't capturing this difference.

Comment: Do you mean the php associative array is inefficient for my kind of JSON output? Sorry, I am not familiar with php.

Comment: NO, I'm just saying that you need to reformat your data so it's in the same format as the JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
// original array
$a = array(
   'Location_1' => 'Link_1',
   'Location_2' => 'Link_2'
);
// transform
$b = array();
foreach($a as $key=>$value) {
    $b[] = array('Location_name'=>$key, 'Link_name'=>$value);
}

// output
echo json_encode($b);

?>
```

Result:

```
[{"Location_name":"Location_1","Link_name":"Link_1"},{"Location_name":"Location_2","Link_name":"Link_2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use StdClass anonymous Objects.

```
<?php


$newArray = array();

$array = array(
  'Location_1' => 'Link_1',
  'Location_2' => 'Link_2'
);



foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

  $object     = new StdClass();
  $object->Location_name = $key;
  $object->Link_name = $value;
  $newArray[] = $object;
}


var_dump(json_encode($newArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

So first things first:

> convert it into a json output using json_encode() that looks like this

This is not possible. `json_encode` just encodes arrays to JSON, you need to do the formatting work yourself.

### And on that note

[`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) should do the trick.

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
    'Location_1' => 'Link_1',
    'Location_2' => 'Link_2'
);
    
$output = array_map( 
    function( $key, $val ){
        return array(
            "Location_name" => $key,
            "Link_name" => $val
        );
    }, array_keys( $arr ), $arr );
        
echo json_encode( $output );
```